# insert tab in string resources in Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, resources

I know I can insert new line with shift+enter
but how can I insert tab?

Comment: Can you not use "\n" to represent the new-line character in a string?

Comment: Erm, the resource editor does not support Shift+Enter.  What version of VS and what *exact* resource are you editing?

Comment: VS treats the EOL as "\n" - or **OA** Hex in binary resources, but actual tabs are not converted to "\t" in the strings, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use \t in your resource string. But pay attention on the fact that if you're using your resource string in a Web Context it won't work.  If it's the case, put a `<pre>` tag before your resource string and a `</pre>` at the end. This way it will work well.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of C#, simply include \t